# Highcharts dont display statistics with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, highcharts

Highcharts dont display statistics with MySQL Query

It Works:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( gt ) as sayi , FROM_UNIXTIME( tarih, '$periyot' ) AS gun
                            FROM sayigoruntu
                            WHERE tarih >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and gt='$gt'".$sqlek."
                            GROUP BY gun
                            ORDER BY gun");
```

Output:

```
[[3582],[2062],[140],[4425],[294]]
```

`$this->db->last_query()` Result:

```
SELECT COUNT( gt ) as sayi , FROM_UNIXTIME( tarih, '%Y.%m.%d' ) AS gun FROM sayigoruntu WHERE tarih >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and gt='0' GROUP BY gun ORDER BY gun
```

This works without problems but this doesn't work (PHP):

```
if($siteid !=''){
$sqlek="and sid='".$siteid."'";
}
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT( gt ) as sayi , FROM_UNIXTIME( tarih, '$periyot' ) AS gun
                            FROM sayigoruntu
                            WHERE tarih >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and gt='$gt'".$sqlek."
                            GROUP BY gun
                            ORDER BY gun
```

Output:

[[3582],[2062],[140],[4425],[294]]

```
$this->db->last_query() result:

SELECT COUNT( gt ) as sayi , FROM_UNIXTIME( tarih, '%Y.%m.%d' ) AS gun FROM sayigoruntu WHERE tarih >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and gt='0' GROUP BY gun ORDER BY gun
```

Same Output, Same Queries but **not working**. Error reason maybe  **".$sqlek."** on MySQL Query.

Is MySQL Query Right Or is this a Highcharts Error?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is incorrect, it should be array of numbers or array of arrays but including x/y. Not an array of arrays with single value. How you refer your data to javascript?

Comment: my highcharts is working with same values. but i add mysql query in  ".$sqlek." dont work.

Comment: Well, but your output doesnt look like [3582,2062,140,4425,294]